# Why does Azure storage have such a low IOPs and throughput compared to local drive?

Tags: azure-storage, solid-state-drive

On my machine's 512 GB SSD, someone should be able to easily get 50000 IOPs.  Why is it that the P20 Azure Premium SSD can only get 2300 IOPs?  And it is still so expensive.

Answer (score 0):

The following article (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview) explains different Azure disk roles and types.

I believe you were comparing temporary disks with the premium SSD which are data disk which can persist data. Every VM contains a temporary disk, which is not a managed disk. The temporary disk provides short-term storage for applications and processes and is intended to only store data such as page or swap files. Data on the temporary disk may be lost during a maintenance event event or when you redeploy a VM. Data disks on the other hand is a Managed Disk type which enables you to persist the data on the disk. Further, it provides provisioned performance, i.e, we make sure you achieve 2300 IOPS for P20 Premium SSD disk. There are other benefits of Managed Disks (please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview). Please drop us an email at AzuredisksPM@microsoft.com, if you need additional info.

Aung Oo, Program Manager, Azure Storage Engineering Team,
Microsoft